# how to find n choose r without overflow

Tags: java, overflow

I need to find the value of n choose r- the number of ways of selecting r objects out of n.

if i first find the numerator then the denominator. i get an exception.

i am using java.

how to do it for example for 44 choose 42

Comment: You'll find many good answers here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201113/combinatoric-n-choose-r-in-java-math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fact that `NcR` is equal to `Nc(N-R)`.  The formula is:

```
 N * (N - 1) * ... * (N - R + 1)
---------------------------------
         1 * 2 * ... * R
```

You can observe that product of `K` consecutive numbers is always divisible by `K`.  So, the loop would look like

- multiply two numbers from nominator
- divide by 2
- multiply by the 3rd number from nominator
- divide by 3
- ...
- multiply by the last number from the nominator
- divide by `R`

Alternatively, just use `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: +1. Good solution. You get NcK in the process, so you can do memoization if needed.