# Choose function in Java math?

Tags: java, math, theory

Sorry about the ambiguous title, I basically need to know how to use the choose function in java, to work out the chance of something happening, for example say I wanted to work out my chance of winning the lottery, on a calculator I'd do:

`QUANTITY_OF_LOTTERY_NUMBERS CHOOSE 6`

and that would return  the chance of those six numbers appearing at random. I believe it's called the binomial theorem, but I dropped out of college before I could learn anything else about it :P

Anyway, if you do `49 choose 6` on Google for example, you'll see the function I'm trying to use

Question: How do I implement this function in Java code?

Comment: `How do I implement this function in Java code?` Do you want us to write it for you? If not, what specific problem are you having?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I think the question means - is there a JDK class or some class in a common library that has this function.

Comment: I'm just curious if there is a `Math.choose(49, 6);` that I skipped over?

Comment: And the answer is in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201113/combinatoric-n-choose-r-in-java-math - and this question is an obvious duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons Math has it. If you are curious, you can read about Pascal's triangle.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/CombinatoricsUtils.html#binomialCoefficient(int, int)