# Code not returning a large enough decimal number

Tags: java

```
 public static double jackpotChance(int k, int highestNumber, int m)
    {
        long temp = 1;
        long tempK = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            temp = temp * (highestNumber-i);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        for(int u = 0; u < k; u++)
        {
            tempK = tempK * (k-u);
            System.out.println(tempK);
        }
        double jackpotChance;
        jackpotChance = (temp/tempK)*m;
        return jackpotChance;
    }
```

Going above ~30 for highestNumber will give a false number for temp thus giving me a false number for jackpotChance. I have heard of BigNumber in the java.math class, and I tried to use that, but it wouldn't let me convert to between number types for some reason. Any advice would be much appreciated. Yes this is a homework problem, so if you can give advice without giving the answer that'd be great thanks :)

edit: added the BigInteger for reference. The error I'm getting is it can't convert the 1 into a BigInteger.

```
 public static BigInteger jackpotChance(int k, int highestNumber, int m)
    {
        BigInteger temp = 1;
        BigInteger tempK = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            temp = temp * (highestNumber-i);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
         for(int u = 0; u < k; u++)
        {
            tempK = tempK * (k-u);
            System.out.println(tempK);
        }
        BigDecimal jackpotChance;
        jackpotChance = (temp/tempK)*m;
        return jackpotChance;
    }
```

Comment: You should provide the code that shows your issue with `BigInteger` to let us help you. Otherwise, if you are looking for the solution, then I guess it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2929897/3707125).

Comment: good idea. Provided code.

Comment: This code returns a binary number, not a decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use doubles too for temp and tempk? That would solve your problem.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: does double store more digits than long? I thought they were the same just one could store decimals and one couldn't.

Comment: @YassinHajaj guess it's a comment. Sorry, I'm fairly new here and i wasn't able to comment a while ago.


Andrew you can check that out by looking at these values:

    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE);

Answer (score 0):

Working with big numbers, I think the best option if you're not using decimals is to use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

It has a special [`BigInteger#multiply`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply(java.math.BigInteger)) method that would solve your problem here.

Do not forget that a `BigInteger` object is immutable so when performing an operation on it, do not forget to assign its value to a variable.

---

### Example

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("10");
big = big.multiply(new BigInteger("20")); // value of big = 200;
```

Comment: O okay thanks. I've never had to work with the BigInteger class before this helped.

Comment: @Andrew You're welcome. An upvote/accept is always free to give :).