# Finding pairs and finding the value of m variable

Tags: java

If a [i] is equal for m pieces different i, how do we get the number of equal pairs it gives rise to? (If
m <2 there will be no pairs at all, if m = 2 there will be one pair, if m = 3 there will be three pairs, if m = 4 there will be
the six pairs,… What will it be in general?)

```
int [] a = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1 };
```

I have used the following method but it doesn't give me full answer when it comes to figuring out the answer for m?

```
int pairs = 0;
int m = 0; 
N = array.length
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
          for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++) { 
            if (array[i] == array[j])  
                    pairs++; 
           }
       return pairs;
        }
```

It gives 3 as an output for pairs but an explanation of how to find out m will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What answer does it give you and do you understand why?

Comment: Thanks for the approach! It gives me 3 as an output, yes because Im only looking for pairs but can not really understand the concept of using m? I mean the overall concept of the question?

Comment: You should check out "stackoverflow.com/help" for help on how and what to ask.  
https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: I have already checked that before asking for help! Did enough approaches myself but didn't upload all the unnecessary stuff. Btw thanks for ur comment!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201113/combinatoric-n-choose-r-in-java-math

Comment: Start with a much smaller list - 2-3 entries - and see if you get what you expect.

Comment: Not depended on the number of entries in the list.